# Why is the Tab title text is disappearing in TabWidget pyqt5 designer?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt5, designer

I am designing a GUI in pyqt5 using Designer. I created a TabWidget and added a few tabs. The text showed fine on all of them until recently the text on the selected tab becomes invisible once I select it.

What can I do to make the text visible again?

And what could I have done to accidentally cause this to happen?

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you perform any upgrade on your system lately? Or did you change some system preferences?

Comment: Yes @musicamante, I recently upgraded to Big Sur. About system preferences, I change them all the time, which one could cause a problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, MacOS has a long and known history of breaking things between versions, and frameworks are not always able to "keep up". Right now the issue is known and in progress: see [QTBUG-86513](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86513) ([QTBUG-85940](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85940) specifically refers to QTabWidget, but it's marked as dupicate for 86513). As far as I can understand from the log of that main report, it should have been fixed for Qt6, but not for Qt5 yet. As a temporary workaround you might consider using `tabWidget.tabBar().setTabTextColor()`.

Answer (score 0):

@musicamante answered this question in the comment, he said that updating macOS may be the cause of the problem and this is a known issue in QT (see his comments above for links to the issue).

The solutions may be to use Pyqt6 or use tabWidget.tabBar().setTabTextColor() to set the color.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to select the QTabWidget in Qt Designer; select the stylesheet ...; select the Add Color drop down menu; set the selection-background-color to blue. The white text then shows up.